# Script is not continuing its search

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python.  I recently wrote a basic web scraping script that uses BeautifulSoup. The script is designed to search a specific for changes.  If changes are found then the script alerts me via email.

I'm having a issue where the script fails when it reaches a certain point.

If you have an answer to the problem or have a better way of accomplish this task please let me know.

Here's part of my code:

```
import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import requests

    url = 'http://www.google.com'

    page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

 #Everything seems to work up to here.

    while True:
        if str(soup).find("arenas") == -1:
            time.sleep(60)
            continue

    else:
        msg = 'Subject: Check'
        fromaddr = 'Sending Email'
        toaddrs = ['1','2','3']

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login("Sending Email", "Sending Password")

        print('From: ' +fromaddr)
        print('To: ' +str(toaddrs))
        print('Message: ' +msg)

        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
        server.quit()
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Also, make it complete. What is `soup`? How is it initialized?

Comment: This looks like he is using beautiful soup. Please post the entire script Reggie

Comment: Where is the error occurring in your code?

Comment: I'll put the rest of the code in now, as far as errors go, there is none. It just doesn't continue.

Comment: Your code is still invalid due to incorrect indentation, and we still do not know _where_ you initialize `soup`. The key to your problem may be there.

Comment: Is it not initialized at the import.  >  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup